# Escaping variables globally

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

To get the results of the queries I use the following methods:

```
$result = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql)->getResult();
```

Where $dql variable is simply the DQL query string. The problem is that when I add an apostrophe in the query string's variable, for instance:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = 'Foo's'
```

Which in reality is just typing `Foo's` string in the input, gives me the symfony error because the query string is not escaped.

How can I solve this issue?

I have A LOT of getResult() methods in my project, and a lot of queries, so I don't really want to change the whole concept of writing queries.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: you need to escape the single quotes with a `\` backslash character.

Comment: But I can't expect users to prepend all single quotes with backslashes in forms.

Comment: And by the way, addslashes() doesn't help, it still gives me errors in " ... '%" . addslashes($string) . "%' ... "

Comment: `I can't expect users to prepend all single quotes with backslashes in forms`... Wow just wow. It's the developer who needs to validate and adapt user input. NEVER trust an user his/her input!
You should take a look into prepared statements and/or PDO

Comment: @khernik Did you solve your problem with my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution: rewrite queries to :bindVariables.
Rookie solution: Create onKernelRequest event and modify everything in Request object
Worst solution: modify $_POST, $_GET and recreate request from globals in app.php

P.S.
No queries outside repositiories:)
http://www.slideshare.net/kriswallsmith/how-kris-writes-symfony-apps